# Где хранить одиночные данные?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, хранение-данных

Здравствуйте, уже давно задаюсь одним вопросом. К примеру у меня есть сайт-система тестирования. Там есть вопросы ну понятное дело их нужно хранить в БД. А вот есть информация, которая может редактироваться в админке такая как(заголовок сайта, описание, контактные данные, заголовок результата теста, описание результата теста), с ней я не знаю как поступить, на данный момент использую зашифрованные .txt файла, но думаю это не самый лучший вариант... Думаю может XML, но как бы это не связные данные... может кто-нибудь подскажет как и где это лучше произвести, главное чтобы была возможно читать и менять эти данные.

Comment: Чем не устроила все та же база?

Comment: Ну создавать таблицу, где будет одна запись? Притом совсем не связные поля получаются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в базе таблицу с двумя полями `name`, `value` и храните все данные там. Поле `name` сделайте уникальным.